# Xml parse issue in JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

i am trying to parse xml Stream from third party url. in my console it is looks like.

`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <string>CMSDocs</string>
      <string>CRMIncomingDocs</string>
      <string>CRMOutgoingDocs</string>
      <string>Customized Reports</string>
      <string>scripts</string>
      <string>Site Assets</string>
      <string>Site Pages</string>
      <string>Style Library</string>
    </ArrayOfString>
```

`

and i am getting error following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:481)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:168)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:137)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:184)
    at com.cms.webservice.converter.BaseMarshaller.convertToObject(BaseMarshaller.java:41)
    at com.cms.webservice.converter.BaseMarshaller.main(BaseMarshaller.java:90)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:388)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1411)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1058)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:195)
    ... 5 more
Java Result: 1
```

but it is working with XML like

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ArrayOfString>
    <string>Kshitij-1</string>
    <string>Kshitij-2</string>
    <string>Kshitij-3</string>
    <string>Kshitij-4</string>
    <string>Kshitij-5</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

`

thanks

Comment: What schema (java classes or such like) are you trying to parse it into...

Comment: this is java class                                     @XmlRootElement(name="ArrayOfString")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ArrayOfString {
    
    @XmlElement(name="string")
    ArrayList<String> stringList=new ArrayList<String>();

    public ArrayList<String> getStringList() {
        return stringList;
    }

    public void setStringList(ArrayList<String> stringList) {
        this.stringList = stringList;
    }

  
}

Comment: Those two pieces of XML are completely different due to the xmlns namespace in the first one. Which of these is correct?

Comment: the last is correct.                                                                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ArrayOfString>
    <string>Kshitij-1</string>
    <string>Kshitij-2</string>
    <string>Kshitij-3</string>
    <string>Kshitij-4</string>
    <string>Kshitij-5</string>
</ArrayOfString>

Comment: The first file's root element doesn't make much sense. There are two ns prefix declarations (xsd and xsi), but they aren't used anywhere. xsi is usually needed to specify the schema location and xsd to specify element types, but all that stuff is absent here.

Comment: yes. it is working without xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/". the problem is this thing is generated by the framework so i have to find another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `@XmlSchema` annotation to specify namespace qualification.  Package annotations are placed on a special class called `package-info` that must reside in the same package as your domain classes.  Below is an example that would work for your use case.

**package-info**

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", 
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: OK, that works, but I would think it's worth explaining why. The first document (from the source) sports a schema namespace, which qualifies the document, and (like @davidfrancis noted) makes it different from the last document, which has no namespace. JAXB is schema namespace sensitive, so a class may have a 'compatible structure' with the document, but JAXB relies on the proper annotation given above to properly associate it with the intended namespace. Bottom line, it is essential to understand xml schema namespaces in order to use JAXB frustration-free.